# Deutsches Wort für »Fracking«

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

Wenn Sie die Möglichkeit hätten, *Fracking* einen neuen, deutschen Namen zu geben, wie würde dieser dann lauten?

Comment: Ich habe kein Problem damit, Fachbegriffe, die eine klar definierte Bedeutung haben, ins Deutsche zu übernehmen. Umgekehrt ist das ja auch der Fall. *aufbau principle, eigenvector, doppelgänger, Energiewende, waldsterben, wanderlust, weltschmerz* usw. bis hin zu *Zugzwang* und *Zwitterion* sind lauter deutsche Wörter, die fest im englischen Wortschatz verankert sind. Außerdem ist Deutsch auch voller französischer Wörter: *Abonnement, Affaire, Akteur, Annonce, apropos, Armee, Attrappe, Au-pair, Avantgarde, ...* (Das waren nur ein paar, die mit A beginnen) Warum stört das niemanden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Druckaufbrechung

---

»*Fracking*« ist die Kurzform von »*Hydraulic Fracturing*«, und das würde man auf Deutsch

> **hydraulische Frakturierung**

nennen.

Nun sind aber sowohl »*hydraulisch*« als auch »*Frakturierung*« Lehn- bzw. Fremdwörter. Wenn es ein richtiger deutscher Name sein soll, muss man also diese Wörter ins Deutsche übersetzen.

- **hydraulisch**

  Dieses Wort ist die eingedeutschte Form des griechischen Adjektivs υδραυλική [*hydrauliké*], das sich zusammensetzt aus:

  > ὕδωρ [*hýdor*] = das Wasser
  >   αὐλός [*aulós*] = das Rohr

  Das Adjektiv »*hydraulisch*« heißt auf Deutsch also eigentlich »*wasserrohrisch*«.
- **Frakturierung**

  Damit ist die Herbeiführung einer Fraktur, oder mehrerer Frakturen, gemeint. Das Wort Fraktur ist wiederum lateinischen Ursprungs:

  > frāctūra = der Bruch

  Das Substantiv »*Frakturierung*« kann also mit »*Brucherzeugung*«, oder, in diesem Fall, mit »*Aufbrechung*« übersetzt werden.

Wenn es also rein deutsch sein muss, dann käme dieser Begriff in Frage:

> wasserrohrische Aufbrechung

Das wird aber kein Schwein verstehen. Daher schlage ich vor, das Verfahren in wenigen Worten zu umschreiben:

> Wasserdruckverursachte Gesteinsaufbrechung zur Förderung fossiler Brennstoffe

oder einfach nur

> **Wasserdruckverursachte Gesteinsaufbrechung**

Wenn man will, kann man das sogar zu nur einem Wort zusammendampfen:

> **Druckaufbrechung**

Comment: Das Übersetzen der Wortbestandteile wie in Hydraulik mag ja oft zur Wortbedeutung führen und ansonsten zu überraschenden Einsichten, darf aber nicht mit Übersetzen verwechselt werden. Eine Klospülung hat auch Wasserrohre, aber Du wirst kaum behaupten, das sei Hydraulik. Außerdem kommen in der Hydraulik gegen die naive Sprachanalyse auch Öl, nicht nur Wasser, und Schläuche, nicht nur Rohre zum Einsatz.

Answer (score 3):

Beim Fracking wird durch die Provokation multipler Gesteinsrisse ein Adersystem im Stein geschaffen.
Wie wäre es also mit 
**Rissveraderungssprengung**
**Rissadersprengung**

Answer (score 1):

**Schiene 1:** Übersetze das, was sich Englischsprachige ausgedacht haben, möglichst genau ins Deutsche.
**Schiene 2:** Ziehe bei der Wortfindung auch Alternativen in Betracht.

Da beim Fracking ja nicht die »wasserrohrische Aufbrechung«, sondern das Fördern im Vordergrund steht, wäre so etwas wie 
*Brechförderung / Bruchförderung* vielleicht sinnvoller. Wo es sonst nur *fördern* heißt, ist Fracking *brechen plus fördern.*